# Compare number of duplicated values in 2 excel columns

Tags: excel

Suppose I have following table ,

[image]

I need to know which values in `A` are also present in `B`(including duplicated values), so in the above image I have 2 `C` in `column A`, and 1 `C` in `column B`. It should return `false`

Comment: you can try `COUNTIF` formula..check this https://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/find-duplicate-rows-excel-across-multiple-columns

Answer (score 0):

If i understood well, you want to compare two columns and their values, returning true if they are equal and have the same number of that value or false otherwise.

You could create a column with the desired data, like on my tests i used `C` and `D`.
On `C` you write the data entries and on D you write a formula to compare like this:

[image]

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A:$A;$C2)=COUNTIF($B:$B;$C2);"TRUE_VALUE";"FALSE_VALUE")
```